# npm ERR! missing script: build;

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

[image]

npm ERR! missing script: build; I’ve found it weird, what causes this issue?

Any ideas? I have added the fullstack error including the `package.json`. please also check the `build.sh` code below

#### Fullstack error

```
> eslint --quiet ./simple/js/*.js

npm ERR! missing script: build;
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Did you mean this?
npm ERR!     build

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\jgulle\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-08-18T08_34_05_215Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! encrypt-decrypt-demo@1.0.3 start: `npm run lint && (npm run build; cd server; npm install; node 
server.js)`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the encrypt-decrypt-demo@1.0.3 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.       

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

#### Package.json

```
{
  "name": "encrypt-decrypt-demo",
  "version": "1.0.3",
  "description": "Simple example to encrypt and decrypt files in the TDF spec using Virtru hosted KAS and EAS.",
  "scripts": {
    "build": ".simple/scripts/build.sh",
    "lint": "eslint --quiet ./simple/js/*.js",
    "start": "npm run lint && (npm run build; cd server; npm install; node server.js)",
    "watch": "nodemon --watch ./simple/js --ignore ./simple/js/build --exec 'npm run start'",
    "audit": "audit-ci --config .audit-ci.json"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "browserify": "16.2.3",
    "moment": "2.24.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "audit-ci": "^2.3.0",
    "eslint": "^6.2.1",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^14.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.18.2",
    "nodemon": "^1.19.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.6"
  }
}
```

#### build.sh code

```
cleanup(){
    if [ -f ./simple/js/build/demo-utils.js ]; then 
        rm ./simple/js/build/demo-utils.js; 
    fi
}

build(){
    browserify ./simple/js/browserify.js -o ./simple/js/build/demo-utils.js
}

cleanup && build
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `"build": "./simple/scripts/build.sh"` ? Check you path correction first please.

Comment: what do you mean Sir ?

Comment: @Molda please check the updat sir

Comment: Try making the path as `./simple/scripts/build.sh` And make sure the script is executable

Comment: I tried "scripts": {
    "build": "./simple/scripts/build.sh",            it just the same error

Comment: Does other scripts work? Like `npm run lint`

Comment: yeah sir the lint works

Comment: Try alternating the order of the scripts in package.json, like putting the lint line before the build line. If still doesn’t work it might be a problem with your build.sh?

Comment: Or you could also try changing the build to something like `echo build`

Comment: @Hedy please check the build sh above sir I have added tit

Comment: Your shell script looks ok, have you tried what I said above? If still doesn’t work you can try a different npm package, to find if it’s because of this package or its a problem with the system

Comment: what do you mean try other npm package?

Comment: I mean try to navigate to another npm package that has a build script and run `npm run build` if you like

Comment: I did try running npm run build the error is '.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

Comment: '.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

Comment: Are you sure? How about when the `"build": "echo build"`?

Comment: no error with "build": "echo build" but it did not start the app

Comment: build "cd" "server;" "npm" "install;" "node" "server.js" this is the output @Hedy

Comment: @Hedy I think the issue is in here     "start": "npm run lint && (npm run build; cd server; npm install; node server.js)",

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
"start": "npm run lint && npm run build && cd server && npm install && node server.js
```

It was trying to find a script named 'build;' with the semi colon, so change it to `&&` with spaces

and the build script change it to:

`"build": " bash simple/scripts/build.sh"`

Comment: and i will just remain the build as build": "./simple/scripts/build.sh", ?

Comment: the error now is '.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

Comment: Are you on MacOS or Linux?

Comment: I am using windows Sir :)

Comment: Then why are you using shell script in the first place? Or are you on Git Bash?

Comment: I am using git Sir

Comment: this is the program I am trying to run https://github.com/virtru/encrypt-decrypt-demo

Comment: If you mean Git for windows then check latest updates

Comment: And if you are not using Git Bash (Git for windows) you should try searching ‘how to run shell scripts on windows’ - this will be unrelated to this question

Comment: yeah I am currently using git bash now

Comment: what would be the different running the command inside gitbash ang on a normal terminal ? how would it solve my problem ? thanks

Comment: because you are using windows, only git bash (or Cygwin) will be posix combatible to run the script

Comment: Have you tried what I wrote in the answer above? (The `#!/bin/bash`)

Comment: Ahh okay2...I see

Comment: just a clarification Sir , what do you mean by adding #!/bin/bash on the first line , thank you

Comment: Add that before everything else in your build.sh - just copy and paste it on the first line and put everything else below it

Comment: yeah same result even when I use cmder

Comment: '.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

Comment: What about doing `bash simple/scripts/build.sh` or `sh simple/scripts/build.sh`

Comment: no error , also no reponse , when i run the command

Comment: Well then change the build script to `"build": "bash simple/scripts/build.sh"` or `sh` if that worked for you, of course there wasn’t any response because the script might have ran and no output was needed

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me on git bash

`npm config set script-shell=sh`

You can set the script shell as cmd or sh. The later one works with semicolons.